# Hadoop running sort example on single-node cluster

Tags: sorting, ubuntu, random, hadoop

I am trying to run sort example on Hadoop single-node cluster. First of all, I start the deamons:

`hadoop@ubuntu:/home/user/hadoop$ bin/start-all.sh`

Then I run the random writer example to generate the sequential files as input files.

`hadoop@ubuntu:/home/user/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter rand`

hadoop@ubuntu:/home/user/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar    randomwriter rand

Running 0 maps.

```
Job started: Thu Mar 31 18:21:51 EEST 2011 
11/03/31 18:21:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201103311816_0001 
11/03/31 18:21:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 
11/03/31 18:22:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201103311816_0001 
11/03/31 18:22:01 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0 
Job ended: Thu Mar 31 18:22:01 EEST 2011
```

The job took 9 seconds.

`hadoop@ubuntu:/home/user/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar sort rand rand-sort`

Running on 1 nodes to sort from `hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hadoop/rand`into

`hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hadoop/rand-sort` with 1 reduces.

```
Job started: Thu Mar 31 18:25:19 EEST 2011 
11/03/31 18:25:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0 
11/03/31 18:25:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201103311816_0002 
11/03/31 18:25:21 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 
11/03/31 18:25:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 100% 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201103311816_0002 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 9 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=96 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0 
11/03/31 18:25:34 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0 
Job ended: Thu Mar 31 18:25:34 EEST 2011
```

The job took 14 seconds.

`hadoop@ubuntu:/home/user/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat rand-sort/part-00000`

SEQ#"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritablej"��mY�&�٩�#

I'm new to Hadoop. Is everything I am doing correct, or am I doing something wrong? And my question is, how can I see that the generated data from the randomwritewr and the results from the sort example are correct? From where can I see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your tasktracker isn't started by the time you try to run the job, it doesn't start up instantly. You can run bin/hadoop job -list-active-trackers to see if the tasktracker is up or not, it may take a moment to finish coming up. No tasktracker = no nodes to map the writer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
11/03/31 18:25:20 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 0
```

There is no input, you have to provide a path where the job has to expect his input files.
It seems that the RandomWriter had no Input too, you have to provide Input for every job, otherwise nothing will be launched.

[RandomWriter @ Hadoop Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/RandomWriter)

Comment: It seems like I'm a bit stuck.. Could you please give me some commands that are correct, so that the problem can be fixed?

Comment: look at: TeraSort benchmark suite http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/